# Consolidate data in Excel with VBA

Tags: vba

At some point I need to consolidate data (simply sum duplicated items). I would like to parameterize `Sources:=` argument - actually everything works the way I amused when using option after single quote mark. When using `src` variable I'm getting: Cannot open consolidation source file ([picture attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs6jU.png)). Looking forward for some tips.

Here is the code:

```
Sub Format()

' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+C

    'Definition
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim lRow As Integer
    Dim src As String
        
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
            
    'Format data

    Range("H2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]&""*""&RC[-4]&""*""&RC[-3]&""*""&RC[-2]"
    
    Range("I2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-7]"
    
    ' Find the last non-blank cell in column B(2)
    
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
              
    Set rg = Range("H2", Cells(lRow, 9))
    
    ' AutoFill of formated data
    
    Range("H2:I2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=rg, Type:=xlFillDefault
    
    'Consolidate
              
    src = """" & "'" & wb.Path & "\[" & wb.Name & "]" & ws.Name & "'!R2C8:R" & lRow & "C9" & """"
   
    Debug.Print src
        
    'Range("K2").Consolidate Sources:= _
        "'C:\Users\pl1aji0\Documents\Projekty\USA\2020\L034.00080 Innovation\700\BPM\[test.xlsx]Sheet1'!R2C8:R11C9" _
        , Function:=xlSum, TopRow:=False, LeftColumn:=True, CreateLinks:=False
        
    Range("K2").Consolidate Sources:= _
        src _
        , Function:=xlSum, TopRow:=False, LeftColumn:=True, CreateLinks:=False
       
  
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm strange cannot edit this post and now it looks like I am impolite. Any way just want to say Hi ;)

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: We don't say "Hi", "Bye", or "Thanks" . That content is irrelevant. We also don't use signatures here as every post you make has your profile name in the lower right corner that wells us who posted, so repeating it in text is just clutter.  It would benefit you to read the [help] pages thoroughly to learn how the site works.